# java.lang.RuntimeException: double ID CustomSoapEnvelope.resolveReference

Tags: java, android, soap

I have a probleme in logs I see this :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: double ID
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.resolveReference(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:462)
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at pl.eltegps.pgo.soap.CustomSoapEnvelope.resolveReference(CustomSoapEnvelope.java:29)
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:439)
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:304)
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.read(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:434)
03-22 11:59:53.643 12534-12592/pl.eltegps.pgo W/System.err:     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.readUnknown(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:304)
```

This is me class CustomSoapEnvelope  :

```
public class CustomSoapEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope {

    public static final String TAG = CustomSoapEnvelope.class.getSimpleName();

    public CustomSoapEnvelope(int version) {
        super(version);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeObjectBody(XmlSerializer writer, KvmSerializable obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj instanceof CustomSoapObject) {
            if (!((CustomSoapObject)obj).hasChildNodes()) {
                writer.text(((CustomSoapObject)obj).getPropertyValue());
            }
        }
        super.writeObjectBody(writer, obj);
    }

    @Override
    protected void resolveReference(String id, Object obj) {
        super.resolveReference(id+obj.toString(), obj);
    }
}
```

and I did this :

```
CustomSoapEnvelope envelope = new CustomSoapEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    ht.debug = true;

    try {
        ht.call("\"" + method + "\"", envelope)
```

I don't know what I did wrong , why I have a double id . A spoapi return this :

```
<PGOResult pages_count="1" total_records="1" sync_date="2018-03-21T15:59:33+01:00">
            <status>1</status>
            <PGOList>
               <PGO id="50409">
                  <address full="01-147 KIELCE, TATRZAŃSKA 32 (TALIK DANUTA IRENA )">
                     <country>POLSKA</country>
                     <city>KIELCE</city>
                     <zip>25-000</zip>
                     <street>TATRZAŃSKA</street>
                     <house>32</house>
                  </address>
                  <location lon="20.6513386" lat="50.8959923"/>
                  <last_inventory_date>2016-09-22T00:00:00+02:00</last_inventory_date>
                  <name>01-147 KIELCE, TATRZAŃSKA 32 (TALIK DANUTA IRENA )</name>
                  <building_type_id>12</building_type_id>
                  <description>01-147 KIELCE, TATRZAŃSKA 32 (TALIK DANUTA IRENA )</description>
                  <LoadList>
                     <Load id="156347" comm_id="2879715">
                        <container_type_id>2064299931</container_type_id>
                        <waste_id>21</waste_id>
                        <last_inventory_date>2016-06-02T09:00:35+02:00</last_inventory_date>
                        <cycle_id>29</cycle_id>
                     </Load>
                     <Load id="156348" comm_id="2879716">
                        <container_type_id>2064299931</container_type_id>
                        <waste_id>20</waste_id>
                        <last_inventory_date>2016-06-02T09:00:35+02:00</last_inventory_date>
                        <cycle_id>29</cycle_id>
                     </Load>
                     <Load id="156346" comm_id="2879717">
                        <container_type_id>2064299931</container_type_id>
                        <waste_id>19</waste_id>
                        <last_inventory_date>2016-06-02T09:00:35+02:00</last_inventory_date>
                        <cycle_id>47</cycle_id>
                     </Load>
                     <Load id="123687" comm_id="2879718">
                        <container_type_id>289485416</container_type_id>
                        <waste_id>10</waste_id>
                        <rfid_1>40000003E6B6E3</rfid_1>
                        <last_inventory_date>2016-05-13T08:38:11+02:00</last_inventory_date>
                        <cycle_id>29</cycle_id>
                     </Load>
                  </LoadList>
               </PGO>
            </PGOList>
         </PGOResult>
```

This bug don't repeat in all request , sometimes I don't have this bugs. And I see list in my activity. But on this request and in this data I have a bug. I don't know how I can repair this